# SP2010 Target Audiences option missing from web part settings

Tags: sharepoint-2010, web-parts, target-audience

In a sudden the target audiences option in SharePoint 2010 web part settings gone missing. I have so far tried:

1. IISRESET
2. Checked the User Profile Service is running
3. Make sure the User Profile Service is listed in the web application's service connections
4. Publishing feature was not activated on both PRODUCTION and TEST environment. But the TEST environment target audiences working fine

Any help is much appreciated.

Regards,
Alan

Answer (score 2):

We had the same issue and we found a really simple (and stupid) solution that worked. Simply make a minor meaningless edit to your SharePoint's web.config like a space or something and save it. It worked for us. Here's where we found this solution:

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/11184/target-audiences-property-not-visible-in-web-part-tool-pane

For us this issue started when we ran several updates this morning at 2:00 AM and rebooted.

Answer (score 1):

Ran into this issue today, our issue was because User Profile was broken. So Target Audiences would not show up.

Our fix was to add the user account for the application pool that was running the virtual app for User Profile Association (under the IIS website SharePoint Web Services), to the permissions of the Service Application.

Go to IIS > expand SharePoint Web Services > highlight Virtual App > click on Advanced Settings in the action pane > look for Identity in the Process Model section (hopefully your appPool naming is helpful!)

Then go to Central Administration for the farm > Manage Service Applications (under Application management) > Highlight The service application > click on permissions up top > Add the name of your Application Pool with full control.

This fixed the issue for us. Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I found the solution for this problem. Was frustrated and got more confused with these misleading answers posted on the internet. Just follow these steps:

Central Admin -> Web Application General Settings -> Select your Web App (on which your site collection is hosted) -> Click on Service Connections from the top ribbon -> Check the User Profile Service Connection and save changes.

This should display the Target Audience property on your web part's Advanced property.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the reasons & solutions for SharePoint 2010 audience targeting missing:

1. Enable audience targeting in SharePoint 2010 Site Collection
   Go to Site Actions >> Site Setting >> Click on "Site collection navigation" >> under Site Collection Administration >> Make sure "Enable Audience targeting" is checked.